# RedirecttoAction with error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I have a link on a grid in my AdminUsers view

```
grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) => (condition ? Html.ActionLink("Impersonate", "Impersonate", "Admin", new { id = item.username }, null) : Html.Label("Impersonate"), style: "webgrid-column-link"),
```

In the controller, I have

```
public ActionResult Impersonate(string id)
{
    string result = ORCA.utilities.users.setImpersonation(id);
    if(result == "nocommonfields")
        return RedirectToAction("AdminUsers", "Admin");
    else
        return RedirectToAction("terms_of_use", "Forms");
}
```

How can send an error message to display when I return to the AdminUsers page?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may use **TempData**

```
if(result == "nocommonfields")
{
    TempData["ErrorMessage"]="This is the message";
    return RedirectToAction("AdminUsers", "Admin");
}
```

and in your AdminUsers action, you can read it

```
public ActionResult AdminUsers()
{
  var errMsg=TempData["ErrorMessage"] as string;
 //check errMsg value do whatever you want now as needed
}
```

Remember, TempData has very short-life span. Session is the backup storage behind temp data.

Alternatively, You may also consider sending a flag in your querystring and read it in your next action method and decide what error message to show.

Comment: is it possible to return default validation errors with tempdata and showing errors in ValidationMessageFor element ?

Answer (score 5):

The [`TempData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx) controller property can be used to achieve this kind of functionality. Its main drawback in my opinion is that it uses the session storage in to store its contents. This means that you'll have extra work getting it to function on a web farm, or that you need to turn on sessions in the first place.

The good thing about `TempData` is that is exactly does what you want. Its a string based dictionary and you can put anything in it and by default get it out only once. So before calling `RedirectToAction()` you set your message. On the next request you check for messages and display them. By retrieving the messages they are automatically deleted at the end of the request.

As an alternative you could use cookies for transporting the message between the two requests. Essentially you could either roll your own solution, or implement a custom [`ITempDataProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.itempdataprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) which transports the contents of `TempData` via cookies. Note that you need to properly secure cookies. [`MachineKey.Protect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx) can help you if you are rolling your own.

I was facing the same problem you did and created a solution for it called **[FlashMessage](https://github.com/Vereyon/FlashMessage)**. Perhaps this could save you some work. It's available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vereyon.Web.FlashMessage) as well. Usage is simple: you simply queue a message before you call `RedirectToAction()` as follows:

```
if(result == "nocommonfields")
{
    FlashMessage.Warning("Your error message");
    return RedirectToAction("AdminUsers", "Admin");
}
```

In your view you include the following statement to render any previously queued messages:

```
@Html.RenderFlashMessages()
```

Comment: Good solution, another possibility is sending it with querystring (of course if it's not a sensitive data).. Although if it's a sensitive data, I'm again not sure about storing it in the cookies (even encrypted with machineKey..) And this kind of thinking leads me to use TempData even though I hate to use it :) But your extension name is FlashMESSAGE and I guess it's not meant to store credit card number in the cookies lol