# Redirect back with message after file upload MVC 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've working on MVC 4 application and want to redirect back with message to call action view:

1. Action that called : Upload
2. Current view : Index

```js
public class HospitalController: Controller {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Model);
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Model model)
        {
            return View(ohosDetailFinal);
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload,FormCollection form)
        {
            //Here i want to pass messge after file upload and redirect to index view with message
            // return View(); not working
        }
}
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Hospital", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" class="hidden" />
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: use `return RedirectToAction(...)` to redirect, and pass the message as a query string value or put it in `Tempdata` and retrieve it in the GET method

Answer (score 1):

Follow the **PRG** pattern. After successful processing, redirect the user to another GET action.

You can return a RedirectResult using `RedirectToAction` method. This will return a 304 response to the browser with the new url in the location header and the browser will make a new GET request to that url.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload,FormCollection form)
{
   //to do : Upload
   return RedirectToAction("Index","Hospital",new { msg="success"});
}
```

Now in the Index action, you may add this new parameter `msg` and check the value of this and show appropriate message. The redirect request will have a querystring with key msg (Ex :`/Hospital/Index?msg=success`)

```
public ActionResult Index(string msg="")
{
   //to do : check value of msg and show message to user
   ViewBag.Msg = msg=="success"?"Uploaded successfully":"";
   return View();
}
```

and in the view

```
<p>@ViewBag.Msg</p>
```

If you do not prefer the querystring in the url, you may [consider using TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958225/redirecttoaction-with-error-message/15958277#15958277). But tempdata is available only for the next request.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload,FormCollection form)
    {
        //Here i want to pass messge after file upload and redirect to index view with message
         return Index();//or with model index
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope It helps.!

View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Hospital", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "" }))
      {

       if (TempData["Info"] != null)
        {
       @Html.Raw(TempData["Info"])
        }


      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      @Html.ValidationSummary()
      <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" class="hidden" />
      }
```

Controller

```
     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload,FormCollection form)
      {
        //Here i want to pass messge after file upload and redirect to index view with message
        TempData["Info"]="File Uploaded Successfully!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
```