# Redirect back with errored rows and message after file upload MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a importFile button the HTML page, upon clicking of it Import File, process the file and return back if there are any errors with a message "File upload Failed with errors. Please check downloaded Error File." If there are no errors, then just "File uploaded successfully" message.
This is what my view looks like:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Plt", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

    {          

       <input type="file" name="file" />
       <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    }
```

Server Side Code:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult ImportFileData(HttpPostedFileBase importFile)
        {
            if (importFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var target = new MemoryStream();
                importFile.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] data = target.ToArray();
                var fileNameWithoutExtension = importFile.FileName.Remove(importFile.FileName.IndexOf("."));
                var file = new FileDetails(fileNameWithoutExtension, data, FileTypes.Xlsx);
                var importedFileDetails = PortalService.ImportFromExcel(file);
                return File(importedFileDetails.FileBytes, importedFileDetails.MimeType, importedFileDetails.FileName);
            }

            return RedirectToAction(MVC.SystemSetup.Index());
        }
```

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Sorry what's your question? You don't seem to have asked us anything or described any kind of problem. All you've done is describe a process, most of which is not covered by the code shown. Are you asking us to write it for you? We won't create a whole feature for you from nothing...instead we'll _help_ you if you are stuck with your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: I am  able to return the FileResult with errored rows. But I also need to return the message File upload Failed. How can I return the File with message .

Comment: Please show your current server side code. We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Since you're redirecting in the case of the file not being provided, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958225/redirecttoaction-with-error-message might help you

Answer (score 0):

On failure. return to the same View and send message and code regarding failure in a ViewBag. Example ViewBage.ErrorMessage and ViewBag.ErrorID.

On View, check if the ViewBag.ErrorID is empty or not. If not empty create a `<div>` which will show the error message as will as a link to download the file.

Somewhat like below code.

```
@if (ViewBag.ErrorID != null)
   {
      <div>
        Error : @ViewBag.ErrorMessage.ToString();
        @Html.ActionLink("Download Error Log", "FileDownloadAction", new { ErrorID = ViewBag.ErrorID });
       </div>
    }
```

The FileDownloadAction should accept the ErrorID as parameter. Using this Error ID you could create the required Error log file. The FileDownloadAction should reutn FileResult.

Comment: Thanks but I dont wanna do one more request to download the file. The errored rows are already returned as FileResult, along with this I need to send message the "Import Failed"